# How to store either rvalue or lvalue references in template

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

I am trying to create a simple template `enumerator` class that should accept any object over which `:` operator is defined and later on print pairs of the form `(i, v[i])`. A simple implementation is the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct enumerator {
    T &v; // reference to minimize copying
    enumerator(T &_v) : v(_v) {}
    void do_enumerate() {
        size_t i = 0;
        for(auto x : v) {
            cout << i << x << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
};
```

This works ok for things like:

**Case A**

```
vector<int> v({1,2,6,2,4});
auto e = enumerator(v);
e.do_enumerate();
```

However, I would also like it to handle temporary objects like:

**Case B**

```
auto e = enumerator(vector<int>({2,3,9});
e.do_enumerate();
```

This does not work and the compiler throws:

```
no matching function for call to ‘enumerator<std::vector<int> >::enumerator(std::vector<int>)
```

So, I tried to then add a

```
enumerator(T _t) : t(_T) {}
```

constructor to resolve this error. Now case A does not work and there is an error:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘enumerator(std::vector<int>&)’ is ambiguous
```

Moreover, in case B, the output of the enumeration is not correct.

What is the cleanest way to solve this? I would

- really like both cases to be working
- prefer not to use any libraries other than stdc++
- want as little copying as possible (thus just storing a `T t` in the struct is not an option)
- C++11 is not a problem. I have g++-4.8, which I presume has complete enough C++11 support.

Comment: Did you try constructors with `T const& ` and `T &&`? You do realize the rvalue will be destroyed once it goes out of scope. Keeping a reference to it in your `enumerator` class isn't going to change that.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `:operator`, that's the syntax of a range-based `for` statement. It creates iterators to `begin()` and `end()` behind the scenes are iterates over the container. There are questions on SO dealing with how they work, search for them.

Comment: And what you're trying to do doesn't make sense. Either copy the argument, or do not accept rvalues.

Comment: Well I would like to copy in case the argument is an rvalue, and not copy in case it is not. Is that possible?

Comment: Considering your goal is to avoid unnecessary copying, you should probably use `for (auto& x : v)` instead of `for (auto x : v)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Well I would like to copy in case the argument is an rvalue, and not copy in case it is not. Is that possible?

This can be accomplished using a `make_enumerator` helper function as shown.

```
template <class T>
struct enumerator {
    T v;
    enumerator(T&& _v) : v(std::forward<T>(_v)) {}
    void do_enumerate() {
        size_t i = 0;
        for(auto x : v) {
            cout << i << x << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
};

template <class T>
enumerator<T> make_enumerator(T&& x) {
    return enumerator<T>(std::forward<T>(x));
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v {5, 2, 9, 1};
    make_enumerator(v).do_enumerate();
    make_enumerator(std::move(v)).do_enumerate();
}
```

**How does this work?**

If the argument to `make_enumerator` is an lvalue of type `A` then `T` is deduced as `A&` and we get the enumerator `enumerator<A&>`, whereas if it is an rvalue of type `A` then `T` is deduced as `A` and we get the enumerator `enumerator<A>`.

In the first case the member `enumerator::v` will have type `A&`, an lvalue reference that binds to the constructor argument (no copying). In the second case the member will have type `A`. The use of `std::forward` casts the parameter `_v` to an rvalue, so it will be moved from when it is used to initialize `v`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 If `T` is an lvalue reference then `T&&` is the same type (not an rvalue reference). Besides, I tried this code already.

Comment: Cool. This works for all scenarios. I will try to understand `std::forward` more. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic example where you don't actually need a `class`/`struct` (which actually introduce useless code) and you can just use good old functions:

```
template<typename Container>
void enumerate(const Container& t) {
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for(auto it = t.begin(); it != t.end(); ++it, ++i)
        std::cout << i << *it << std::endl;
}
```

and then call it as:

```
enumerate(std::vector<int>{2,3,9});
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e54d3487fa1a957)

With this method you also get argument type inference for free (which you don't get with a `struct`).

Comment: Thanks. That works. However, it would be good to have an object since I plan on actually defining an iterator interface to the `enumerator` class itself. So that way I can do `for(auto p : enumerate<vector<int>>(whatever)) {}`.

Comment: @SubhasisDas Right, that's really useful because `vector` by itself doesn't support that ... oh wait

Comment: @SubhasisDas If you are planning on creating a range-like struct, please consider using [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) (or at least take inspiration from it).

Comment: I know that boost has probably all the functionality I want. However, I would like to myself know about the new features in C++11, and so this is more of an educational endeavor than anything else. I will look into boost.range api.